# Azure Functiion written in Portal (CSX) with external referenced nuget package does not work

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to make a very simple blobtriggered function, I cannot seem to make this work.
Anyone any idea what is wrong here?

Code:

```
#r "SixLabors.ImageSharp"
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

 

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, Stream imageSmall, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Bolob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

    using var image = Image.Load(myBlob);
    int width = image.Width / 2;
    int height = image.Height / 2;

    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
    image.Save(imageSmall);
}
```

Function.proj

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <TargetFramework>.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1</TargetFramework>

</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>

     <PackReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.2"/>

</ItemGroup>
```

Of (doesn’t seem to matter):

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>

</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>

     <PackReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.2"/>

</ItemGroup>
```

Error:
“Error] run.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'SixLabors.ImageSharp' could not be found”.

Comment: try changing PackRefrence to PackageRefence in function.proj

Comment: stupid me and Bart, did not see that.... Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @*MohitGanorkar-Mt* for point out the solution ,posting it as answer to benefit for other community members for the similar issue.

> Error: “Error] run.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file
> 'SixLabors.ImageSharp' could not be found”.

For the above We have tried to create an Azure function using blob trigger and it works fine as well from our end .

The `function.csproj`  you have `item group` with `packreference` instead of that we have to use as shown below:

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <TargetFramework>.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1</TargetFramework>

</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>

     <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.2"/>

</ItemGroup>
```

similarly with 2.1 as well

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>

</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>

     <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.2"/>

</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

For more information please refer this BLOG|[***Create an Azure Function Triggered By Blob Storage Using C#***](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-azure-function-triggered-by-blob-storage-using-c-sharp/) by @*Jay Krishna Reddy*.

Comment: Thanks! stupid mistake copying..